# How do I properly create a connection in relay & graphql schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js, relaymodern

I am trying to create a pagination in relay & graphql in my schema. This is my code:

```
const GraphQLFriendByUser = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FriendByUser',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('FriendByUser'),
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (root) => root._id,
    },
    email: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: (root) => root.email,
    },
    fullName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (root) => {
        return root.fullName;
      },
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

const {
  connectionType: FriendsByUserConnection,
  edgeType: GraphQLFriendByUserEdge,
} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'FriendByUser',
  nodeType: GraphQLFriendByUser,
});
```

I created this similarly looking at sample in todo-modern, In my TodoListHome component, this is my graphql query:

```
friendsByUserContext( first: 200 ) @connection(key: "TodoListHome_friendsByUserContext") {
      id
      _id
      fullName
      email
    }
```

there's no problem when I update the schema, but when I try to build, this is my error:

> Invariant Violation: RelayParser: Unknown field `id` on type
>   `FriendByUserConnection`. Source: document `TodoListHome_viewer` file:
>   `C:\Users\PE60\Desktop\socialnetworking-todoapp\js\components\TodoListHome.js`.

The execution doesn't even reach on resolve, so I cannot log. but I believe the error is not from there. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `graphql-js`, you probably have graphiql hosted on your `/graphql` endpoint. That's a good place to debug queries and see the structure of your schema. There you'll see that the connection you're talking about has the field `edges` which has the field `node` which has the fields you're looking for.